# create a shortcode with a PHP include for use in WordPress posts and pages

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

I am wondering if there is a way to create a shortcode to use in the visual page builder on a page in Wordpress that would allow me to use it as a PHP include. I need to add some PHP code from a file called form.php into my page and the visual page builder only let's you add HTML. I would prefer not to use a plug-in if possible. I need to use this code but it's not recognizing it.

```
<?php include 'form.php';?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - you can have a shortcode that takes one parameter (the file to include) and simply outputs its content:

```
add_shortcode('include', 'include_php_file');
function include_php_file($atts=array(), $content='') {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'file' => ''
    ), $atts);
    if(!$atts['file']) return ''; // needs a file name!
    $file_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$atts['file']; // adjust your path here
    if(!file_exists($file_path)) return '';
    ob_start();
    include($file_path);
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for answering, do I add this in the functions.php file? and then what would the shortcode be that I can use on the page?

Comment: Oh - sorry, missed that part, didn't I? So yes, you would add this to your theme's function.php file. (If it's not your own theme, I hope you made a child theme!)

Then to use it, simply put this in any page or post's content box:

[include file='form.php']

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the template for that page and conditionally include that file only for that post.

es:

```
if( is_page('contact') include('path/to/file.php');
```

if you need that file in more than one page pass an array to `is_page`:

```
if( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact', 'management' ) ) 
     //either in about us, or contact, or management page is in view
     include('path/to/file.php');
else
     //none of the page about us, contact or management is in view
```